# Power limitations for Ethernet cabling

Tags: power, ethernet, cables, standard, poe

I have a 60 watt constant current Meanwell driver that has the following output options:
.9 amps  @ 67 volts or 57 volts @ 1.05 amps. I want to know what specific ethernet cable is required.  Can I use a Cat6 cable that has two pair for power or do I need three pair wired for power? I am confused by the IEEE802.3bt standard.

Comment: Wiring a power supply directly to Ethernet wiring has nothing to do with 802.3bt and will fry any devices not supporting PoE. 802.3bt requires handshake communication to turn power on and 4 pairs required for 60W. In any case, why put a constant current power supply there?

Comment: You hit a regulatory barrier somewhere around 60VDC -- I can't remember the exact number, but below it you can follow "telephone wiring rules" and above it you have to follow house wiring rules.  The amount of user protection required is significantly different and can affect product cost and/or the amount of care you need to take in implementing your wiring in a commercial environment.

Comment: I think that "barrier" is 50 V.  That's why a lot of teleco equipment is powered with 48 VDC.

Answer (score 1):

Check on the cable itself, as it will depend on the insulation of the cable. I've seen CAT6 cable that can support 90V and CAT5 cable that can support 48V, but again you'll have to check on the actual cable specs for something rated over 60V. I'd imagine almost any ethernet cable can support regular 48-57V voltages of POE.